# Formula not copying correctly using VB

Tags: excel, excel-2007, vba

I hoping someone can explain what I'm doing wrong here as I would like to get a clear understanding of how to do this correctly.  When I copy the following formula from cell (C10) on one tab to cell (AC3) on another tab the "$B10 portion "#ref!" - yet the remaining portion looks fine.  Can some please tell me what I need to do and what is causing issue - Thank you.

Formula (Cell C10 on one tab):

=IFERROR(SUMIFS($O:$O,$B:$B,$B10)/COUNTIFS($B:$B,$B10,$O:$O,"<>0"),"")

VB Code to copy is:

```
Sheets(gcsCombinedSheetName).Cells(lngLastRow, columnletter) = getConfigPosition.Offset(0, 2).Formula
```

Thanks,

Ciaran.

Comment: Try `Sheets(gcsCombinedSheetName).Cells(lngLastRow, columnletter).FormulaR1C1 = getConfigPosition.Offset(0, 2).FormulaR1C1`

Comment: Good morning Peter.  You must live "in" this form...!!!!  But I'm grateful of the fact.  Thanks for your input.  I get a "Run-time error 424" (object required).  Is it a case now that I need to write the formula with RC[ ] references as opposed to $B10 etc?

Comment: @user1624926 A1 is R1C1, B1 is R1C2

Comment: Seems like both Peters live here! ;-) Please provide a bit more code/background to your question if you want a good answer. I do not understand what the issue you desvribe in the first paragraph has to do with the VBA in the bottom...

Comment: THanks to both of you as always.   When I apply the ".formulaR1C1" it tells me I need an object.  I thought because I added the R1C1 that I needed to write the formula using RC [ ] etc.  I can't (or at least I don't think you can) add code to the comment box.  I will close this question and put it in a new question with the full code.

Comment: Is `getConfigPosition` a Range data type??

Comment: ... You can also just update this question rather than posting a new one...

Comment: Sorry for the late response John - had issues logging back on (PC).  Thanks for your support.  I'm only getting the hang of this form and I appreciate all the help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks t0 Peter L and Peter S for the support on this one.  I replaced .formula with .formulaR1C1 and wrote the formula using the related referencing.  I then put an error checker on it and I could clearly see what elements of the code that where out of range.

Thanks again,

Ciaran.